# SHA1 Hash not the same between Windows Phone 8.1 app and UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, sha1, windows-10-universal

In Windows Phone 8 I was able to do something like this:

```
 SHA1Managed s = new SHA1Managed();
 UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();
 s.ComputeHash(enc.GetBytes(password.ToCharArray()));
 string hash = BitConverter.ToString(s.Hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
```

For UWP App I am doing:

```
IBuffer buffUtf8Msg = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(password, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);

HashAlgorithmProvider objAlgProv = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Sha1);

IBuffer buffHash = objAlgProv.HashData(buffUtf8Msg);

if (buffHash.Length != objAlgProv.HashLength)
{
    throw new Exception("There was an error creating the hash");
}

string strHashBase64 = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(buffHash);

string hash = strHashBase64.Replace("-", "").ToLower();
```

I am not getting the same result.

For example, if I had the text "Windows 8",  I would get

`6517856f8c3a3fda3ae28305a05d127f0e1bdb97` (Windows Phone 8.1)

and

`zrefb4w6p9o64omfof0sfw4b25c=` (UWP)

I dont quite know what I am doing wrong. The goal is to just get the SHA1 hash of a string.

Comment: Replace `EncodeToBase64String` with `EncodeToHexString`, then you will get the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of encoding to base64 under UWP code (`CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(buffHash)`), you probably want to encode to hexadecimal with:

```
string strHex = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString(buffHash);
string hash = strHex.ToLower();
```

So both of your Windows Phone 8 code and UWP code will produce the same output (*hex encoded* SHA1).